# SQL - Assign Unique ID for DISTINCT records

Tags: sql-server

I need to create at temp table that has two columns: language_id (number) and language (text). I have a customer table that contains my language column. I need to populate my temp table with distinct records from my language column and I need to be able to assign a language_id for each distinct language record.

I am using '`SELECT DISTINCT Language from CustomerData`' to get distinct records, but I am not certain how to assign a language_id for each distinct record.

My desired output is below

```
Language ID     Language
1               English
2               French
3               Spanish
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why not define the `Language_ID` field as IDENTITY ?

Comment: You can add the column language_id as IDENTITY column in your temp table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's Simple group by "Language" on "CustomerData" data and ROW_NUMBER() to assign DISTINCT row number:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Language asc) as ID, Language
from CustomerData
group by Language
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in a table, set Language_ID as IDENTITY. If you want the result of a query, try this:

```
SELECT
    t.Language
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Language_ID
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Language FROM CUSTOMER_DATA) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to achieve the same

```
INSERT INTO temp_table
SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [Language] ) Language_ID,  
    ,[Language] 
FROM CustomerData
ORDER BY Language_ID
```

Otherwise as suggested in comments you can use `Language_ID` as `IDENTITY` column and use the simple query below

```
INSERT INTO temp_table(Language)
SELECT DISTINCT [Language] 
FROM CustomerData
ORDER BY CustomerData
```

Comment: Thank you to all for your responses. I have a few different solutions which I am trying out. I really appreciate all the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
     [Language ID]  =   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Language]) 
    ,[Language]     =   [Language]
FROM
    [CustomerData]
GROUP BY 
    [Language];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be having master / lookup table to gt this ID from that table.
Incase you have it, i would recommoned to use that table and JOIN it in your query to populate language id.

In case you don't have a master table for Language,
You can use **Row_number()** to get distinct rows with LanguageID

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by Language ASC) , Language from
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT Language from CustomerData
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE ##TempLanguage (
    [LanguageId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  -- note use of IDENTITY field to assign LanguageId value
    [Language] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Load the temporary table:

```
INSERT ##TempLanguage (
  [Language]
) 
SELECT DISTINCT [Language] FROM [CustomerData] ORDER BY [Language];
```

Display the temporary table's contents:

```
SELECT [LanguageId], [Language] FROM ##TempLanguage;
```

Remove the temporary table:

```
DROP TABLE ##TempLanguage
```

Note that beginnning the name of a temporary table with a double hash-tag, such as `##TempLanguage`, creates a temporary table that persists between database connections and can be shared between database connections.  Beginning the name of a temporary table with a single hash-tag, such as `#TempLanguage` creates a temporary table that persists for the length of the current connection, and is visible only to the current database connection.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the existing answers, you can add an identity column to your table afterwards.

```
ALTER TABLE <table-name> ADD
    LanguageId int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
```

This will assign an incremental id to all rows currently in the table when the column is added.